# How to make one common H1 element for few sections in React

Tags: reactjs, dom, sections

How to make one common H1 element for sections: Skills and About. If I clicked Skills Button H1 change to Skills and if i clicked About btn H1 change to About. I need this h1 element only for this two section and be oscillated by same value in css. For Start section it shouldn't be. Should I use state/props?

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Contact extends Component {
  get show() {
    return this.props.activeSection === "contact";
  };

    render() {
      if(this.show) {

        return (
          <div className='contact'>
        <h1>kontakt!</h1>
          <a href='' target='_blank'>
            <img src='' />
          </a>
          <a href={cvpdf} target='_blank'>
            <img src='' />
          </a>
          <a href='' target='_blank'>
            <img src='' />  
          </a>
          <a className="mailto" href="">
          <img src='' />
          </a>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return null;
    };
    };
  };

class Skills extends Component {
  get show() {
    return this.props.activeSection === "skills";
  };

    render() {
      if (this.show) {

        return (
          <div className='intro skills'>
          <h1>skills</h1>
          <img src='' alt=''/>
          <img src='' alt=''/>
          <img src='' alt=''/>
          <img src='' alt=''/>
          <img src='' alt=''/>
          <img src='' alt=''/>
          <img src='' alt=''/>
          <img src='' alt=''/>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return null;
    };
    };
  };

class About extends Component {
  get show() {
    return this.props.activeSection === "about";
  };

    render() {
      if (this.show) {
        
        return (
          <div className='intro about'>
         <h1>about</h1>
         <p>
            Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content 
         </p>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return null;
    };
    };
  };

class Start extends Component {
    get show() {
        return this.props.activeSection === "start";
      };

    render() {
    if (this.show) {

        return (
            <div className='intro start'>
              <h1>Name Surname</h1>
              <p>Content Content Content Content Content Content </p>
              <h2>Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content </h2>
          </div>
      );
    } else {
        return null;
    };
    };
  };

const Main = ({ activeSection }) => (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="container border">
          <Start activeSection={activeSection}/>
          <About activeSection={activeSection}/>
          <Skills activeSection={activeSection}/>
          <Projects activeSection={activeSection}/>
          <Contact activeSection={activeSection}/>
        </div>
    </React.Fragment>
);

const Buttons = ({ onToggle }) => (

  <div className="buttons">
          <button name='start' onClick={onToggle}>Start</button>
          <button name='about' onClick={onToggle}>About</button>
          <button name='skills' onClick={onToggle}>Skills</button>
          <button name='contact' onClick={onToggle}>Contact</button>
        </div>
);

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activeSection: "",
    };


    this.handleToggleSection = this.handleToggleSection.bind(this);
  
  };

  handleToggleSection(e) {
    const {name} = e.target;
    this.setState(() => ({
      activeSection: name
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Buttons onToggle={this.handleToggleSection}/>
        <Main activeSection={this.state.activeSection}/>
      </div>
    );
  };
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Please correct me if I'wrong: you want some `h1` that should be displayed in some place of your app out of `Skills` and `About` components with "Skills" text if you click "Skills" button and with "About" test if you click "About" button?

Comment: You are right but not in some place of my app, it should be in Skills and About Component - headline/heading of this section

Comment: And you don't want this element to be replaced in DOM when you click on a button?

Comment: It should be only visible in suitable section - like when I click button Skills, content from Skills component is showing and above it should be this H1 element with text - Skills.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You have already done it. Your `Skills` and `About` components have `h1` with the title of the section.

Comment: Yes but I only wondering how to make it using state and props

Comment: You don't need state nor props for doing that. What's the purpose of it? I really dont' understand.

Comment: Just for practising and more understanding state and props

Comment: It's mindful. For practicing purpose regarding your example I'd suggest you make a decision what component to show in `Main` component instead of rendering all the components and duplicate displaying logic in each of them.

Comment: Yhym, ok thanks a lot for ur answers, you were very helpful!! :)